# Integration of pivotal on github not works

Tags: github

I have updated my pivotal token on the github service hooks.But the commits are not retrieving on my pivotal tracker page

Answer (score 1):

Confirm you are clicking the "active" checkbox on the form where you entered the API token in Github.

This hangs me up almost every time. I'd post a screenshot but need more reputation.